# Adding Cookies to a Jquery delayed POPup

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, popup

I am a novice web-designer who can usually pull apart a website to figure out how it works, but I have been researching for 2 days now and I feel I need to ask for some help regarding setting up cookies.

What I am looking to do it have a Delayed popup appear on my page, but I would like it to appear only once every 15 minutes. I have worked out the delayed popup and have a sample here http://2-jobsearch.com/sample

I just need to know how to merge the cookie code into my current popup code..

Here is what I have now..

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js.cookie.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery.popupoverlay.js"></script>

<script>$(document).ready(function () {
$.fn.popup.defaults.pagecontainer = '.container'});</script>
<!-- Fade & scale --><div id="fadeandscale" class="well"><pre class="prettyprint"> POP</pre>


<button class="fadeandscale_close btn btn-default">Close</button></div>

<script>setTimeout(function(){ $('#fadeandscale').popup({opacity: 0.5,autoopen: true,transition: 'all 3.3s'});},5000);</script>
```

I would appreciate any help or thoughts on a solutions or if this question has been asked and solved, please let me know as I could not find the answer.

Thanks 
Scott